# Varnish chef cookbook director erb file

Tags: templates, chef-infra, varnish

How do I change the erb file to add first five nodes to director director1 and others to director2

```
My current erb file. 
director director1 round-robin {
<%- if !(node['varnish']['backend_servers']).nil? -%>
  <%- node['varnish']['backend_servers'].each do |server| -%>
    { .backend = <%= server[:hostname] %>; }
  <%- end %>
<%- end %>
}
```

Comment: You should consider to do the business logic in your recipe and separate the nodes into two sets then apply here in your template.